# DocuSignAPI Adding Note for Recipient 2 SOAP

Tags: docusignapi

I am using SOAP API and have integrated DocuSignAPI using .NET.

I have the following code to add a personal note for each of the recipients.

```
    recipient1.note = "this is recipient 1";
    recipient2.note = "this is recipient 2";
```

The note for recipient 1 shows up, but not for recipient 2.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: you probably need to include more code or better yet a SOAP trace of exactly what's getting posted.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me using PHP code.  It's possible this might be a case issue, I am using capitals for the Note property for each of my two recipients.  I'm setting them up as follows:

```
$rcp1 = new Recipient();    // First recipient to put in recipient array
$rcp1->UserName = "John Doe";
$rcp1->Email = $_apiRecipient1Email;
$rcp1->Type = RecipientTypeCode::Signer;
$rcp1->ID = "1";
$rcp1->RoutingOrder = 1;
$rcp1->RequireIDLookup = FALSE;
$rcp1->Note = "Note One";

$rcp2 = new Recipient();    // Second recipient to put in recipient array
$rcp2->UserName = "Joe Mama";
$rcp2->Email = $_apiRecipient2Email;
$rcp2->Type = RecipientTypeCode::Signer;
$rcp2->ID = "2";
$rcp2->RoutingOrder = 1;
$rcp2->RequireIDLookup = FALSE;
$rcp2->Note = "Note Two";
```